# Git: Get all branch names for a given revision

Tags: git

Given a commit hash, what is the best way to get all branch names that point to that commit?

Option 1: Brute force. Use `git for-each-ref refs/heads` to get all branches, filter on commit, and extract branch names.

Option 2: use `git name-rev --name-only`. However, this only gives only *one* branch (if multiple branches point to the same commit).

Ultimately what I really want is a topo-sorted list of branch names between two commits (where commits with multiple branches will have multiple entries). It seems like git probably can do what I want and I'm just not finding the right command.

EDIT: Note that I am *not* asking what branches contain a given commit. I want to know which branches have that commit as their head.

Comment: @phd - No, it's pretty clearly *not* a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @phd - Nope.  The fact that you *could* solve the asked problem once, by solving a different problem twice and operating on the results, does not make them the same question. Note that NEITHER of the answers below suggest using the commands mentioned in your referenced question, because while those commands do properly answer that question they don't properly answer this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly, ways to do this will seem inefficient because it's not an operation that's made "easy" by the data structures involved.  You basically do have to iterate over all the refs, especially if you want *all* the branches that point to the commit.  Commands that simplify this do so by giving you the syntax to express what you want, but still they have to iterate through the refs.  The good news is, that sounds worse than it is.

Note that your second method has another pitfall: it will try to come up with *some* name for a commit even if no branch points to it.  So `master~1`, for example, is valid output for that command.  It also can return `undefined` in the case where a commit is unreachable, but I would think that's not a likely use case.

It sounds like you only want the branches pointing *directly* to the commit (as opposed to every branch that can reach the commit), and that helps as this eliminates the potential need to traverse every ref's history.

So, anyway... yes, your first method is the way to go, with a couple possible refinements.

The `--points-at` option will take care of the filtering for you (unless you're on an older version of git).

The `--format` option can help with extracting the branch name (though it doesn't get you 100% of the way there as far as I know, because you presumably want to strip the `refs/heads/` prefix).

So it might come together like

```
git for-each-ref --points-at $sha1 --format='%(refname)` refs/heads | cut -c12-
```

Comment: It's not ideal, but that is the best thing I've seen and definitely gives me what I need. Thanks!

Comment: `--format='%(refname:short)'` gets you the name without `refs/heads/`. You can also use `:strip=2` here.

Comment: @torek ... DOH.  Missed that

Answer (score 2):

If your Git is new enough, `git for-each-ref --points-at` does just what you want (apply to `refs/heads` namespace and add any formatting you like).

The `--points-at` option was new in Git 2.7.0.  In older versions, you should still use `git for-each-ref` but you will need to filter to just those whose hash ID is the desired one.

---

Worth noting, for your ultimate goal: `git log --decorate` will add reference decorations to commit IDs, so you can use `git log --decorate --format='%H %d'`.  Add `--topo-order` and `--ancestry-path start..end` to get topo-sorted commits that include `end` but exclude `start` and that are descendants of `start` *and* ancestors of `end`.  Omit `--ancestry-path` if you don't want to require the "descendants of" part.  (Consider `--boundary` if you want to include the start commit but beware, `--boundary` selects too many commits sometimes.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips .. that does get me most of the way there, but then I'd need to try to parse apart the branch names in order to work with them. But, I did learn some good things from your answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, parsing the output of `git log` is not the prettiest thing. If I were to write this myself I'd probably start with Python running `git rev-list --topo-order --ancestry-path` and `git for-each-ref refs/heads` and build the rest using dictionary lookup.

Comment: I never saw the "--ancestry-path" option before, so that's a great one to learn. Thanks :)